# How to set `setNumTasks` for a storm bolt in clojure?

Tags: clojure, apache-storm

I would like to set number of tasks for a bolt in my storm topology. But I can't find a way to do this in clojure. I didn't see anything in the documentation either in bolt-spec. Am I missing something? For fine tuning my application I need a way to set number of tasks. Is this possible?

[1] : http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/Clojure-DSL.html

Comment: In Java, it is `builder.setBolt(...).setNumTasks(Number)`. Not sure for Clojure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can pass the number of topology tasks in a configuration map when calling bolt spec like

```
(bolt-spec {"1" :shuffle} geocode-lookup :p 8 :conf {TOPOLOGY_TASKS 64})
```

Here is an example topology:

```clj
(defn heatmap-topology []
  (topology
   {"1" (spout-spec checkins :p 4)}

   {"2" (bolt-spec {"1" :shuffle} geocode-lookup :p 8 :conf {TOPOLOGY_TASKS 64})
    "3" (bolt-spec {"2" :shuffle} time-interval-extractor :p 4)
    "4" (bolt-spec {"3" ["time-interval" "city"]} heatmap-builder :p 4)
    "5" (bolt-spec {"4" :shuffle} persistor :conf {TOPOLOGY_TASKS 4})}))
```

I was too wondering the same thing and found this:

1. `org.apache.storm.clojure/bolt-spec` is an alias for `org.apache.storm.thrift/mk-bolt-spec` [link](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-clojure/src/clj/org/apache/storm/clojure.clj#L198)
2. `bolt-spec` is defined using `org.apache.storm.util/defnk` [link](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/ab66003c18fe4f8c0926b3219408b735b2ce2adf/storm-core/src/clj/org/apache/storm/util.clj#L95), so it returns a map like `{:obj bolt :inputs inputs :p parallelism-hint :conf conf}` with conf defaulting to `nil`
3. `org.apache.storm.clojure/bolt-spec` is an alias for `org.apache.storm.thrift/mk-topology` and calls `org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.addConfigurations` passing `conf` as the only argument. [link](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-clojure/src/clj/org/apache/storm/thrift.clj#L273)
4. Also, `setNumTasks` simple calls `addConfiguration(Config.TOPOLOGY_TASKS, val)`[link](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/ab66003c18fe4f8c0926b3219408b735b2ce2adf/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/topology/BaseConfigurationDeclarer.java#L52)
5. And last, the correct constant for setting the number of tasks for a spout of bolt is `TOPOLOGY_TASKS` [link](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/ab66003c18fe4f8c0926b3219408b735b2ce2adf/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/Config.java#L1568)

Comment: Perfect! I was able to trace it to point 3). I didn't know I just had to pass a map! Thank you. Just tried. It works! :)

Answer (score -1):

According to [Clojure-DSL](http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/Clojure-DSL.html) page:

> To create topology configs, it's easiest to use the
>   `backtype.storm.config` namespace which defines constants for all of the
>   possible configs. The constants are the same as the static constants
>   in the Config class, except with dashes instead of underscores. For
>   example, here's a topology config that sets the number of workers to
>   15 and configures the topology in debug mode:
>
> ```
> {TOPOLOGY-DEBUG true
>  TOPOLOGY-WORKERS 15}
> ```

And from Storm documentation (look for section named "Number of tasks"):

> ### Number of tasks
>
> - Description: How many tasks to create per component.
> - Configuration option: `TOPOLOGY_TASKS`
> - How to set in your code (examples):
>
>   `ComponentConfigurationDeclarer#setNumTasks()`
>
> Here is an example code snippet to show these settings in practice:
>
> ```
> topologyBuilder.setBolt("green-bolt", new GreenBolt(), 2)
>                .setNumTasks(4)
>                .shuffleGrouping("blue-spout");
> ```

It looks like using `backtype.storm.config` namespace and defining `TOPOLOGY-WORKERS` would be equivalent to calling `setNumTasks`.